# Install Python Package from Github

Tags: python, github, installation

I would like to install 10K-MDA-Section  from Github (https://github.com/rflugum/10K-MDA-Section) but when running this command in the prompt:

```
pip install --upgrade git+git://github.com/rflugum/10K-MDA-Section
```

I get this error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
  'C:\\Users\\...\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-1vmt3z0t\\setup.py'

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error 
  code 1 in C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-1vmt3z0t\
```

Any idea what is causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the repository ([`rflugum/10K-MDA-Section`](https://github.com/rflugum/10K-MDA-Section)) does not have a `setup.py` file, a `pip install` won't work.

Check if cloning, and then executing `MDA Extractor.py` directly (`python MDA Extractor.py`)is enough.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Thanks, I will try that approach.

Answer (score 1):

The pip install is looking for a setup.py file and the FileNotFound error implies that the file is not present (Since a pip calls setup.py to proceed with the installation.)

The way forward should be to clone the git repo and then execute `python MDA Extractor.py`

Comment: Isn't this exactly what I just said in my answer?

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. I guess VonC beat you to the punch, but I still appreciate the help. Will try this!!