# How to use non-packaged Python code from GitHub

Tags: python

I'm trying to use the code from [this](https://github.com/cpederkoff/stl-to-voxel) repository. The problem is that it isn't a package (I think?) because it can't be found on PyPI and there's no setup.py file (so I can't use `pip install git+<repo link>`). How would I then be able to use this code in my project?

I've already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59871046/install-python-package-from-github) question, which also involved not having a setup.py file, but the answer seems unsatisfactory to me. I'm under the impression that it wouldn't allow my project to be run on someone else's pc without them also manually installing the code from the aforementioned repo.

I've also thought about just downloading the code and adding a setup.py myself, but I think that would produce the same problem.

I'm clearly a little unclear on this subject and I can't find any explanation/solution anywhere else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That repository doesn't seem to be properly packaged for library use at all.

I'd recommend forking it, making the changes you need to make it usable (moving the files into a package, adding a setup.py) and then using that as a `git+https://` style requirement.

Comment: Exactly, the repo is also under an 
[MIT License](https://github.com/cpederkoff/stl-to-voxel/blob/master/LICENCE.md), which really even allows keeping the source files in the project directly.